# Stumped: Trapezoid problem with law of sin/cos ...

Tags: trigonometry

This one stumped me.
Thought you might enjoy..

What are the lengths of the diagonals?
It should be related to law of sine/cosine.
(The answers are in fraction)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you cut off a parallelogram from the left, you get a triangle with a base of 3 and a top angle of (what?).  The law of sines then gives you the other two sides.  Then restore the parallelogram, draw the diagonals, and use the law of cosines.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you get 3.86 and 4.14 ?

Comment: @JackOfAll:  I got 2.7648 for the left edge and 3.89853 for the diagonal from the 50.  Could just be rounding.